# Unity cannot edit shader property in script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader

I have a material with a custom shader on it. The shader has a property called _sliceValue that I want to edit inside the code. However, this does not happen. I am using the below code but the shader property remains at 0.

I am using unity 2020.3 and HDRP. What am I doing wrong?

```
void Start()
    {
        rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        rend.material.SetFloat("_sliceValue", 0.5f);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but if this is a shadergraph shader, make sure that the reference value and not just the name is "_sliceValue" - you can see it by clicking the property in sg and checking the node window.
If not a sg shader, then could it be an instancing issue? Could try with renderer.sharedmaterial

If nothing works, you can post the shader code, that might give a clue...